# XPath count not converting to Ruby number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to introduce XPath to my Ruby on Rails, Cucumber and Capybara setup for the first time. My code

```
row_count_on_page = page.find(:xpath, "count(//table[@id='foo']/tbody/tr)")
```

is resulting in error

```
undefined method `map' for 10.0:Float
Did you mean?  tap (NoMethodError)
```

The actual XPath part of the code seems to be working correctly because there are exactly ten rows in the body of the table. I don't get how the code can't convert that 10.0 into a Ruby 10 though. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us the actual code line that throws an error (hint: in contains call to `map`.)

Comment: The line of code I am showing is my only line of code. I never call `map` myself. I understand that _something_ is calling it, but whatever it is is doing so behind the scenes, someplace I am not aware of.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We need more information in the question, including the minimal runable code the that demonstrates the problem along with the minimum input HTML and your desired output. A single line of code with no related HTML does little to help us help you. We have to imagineer the HTML which leads to inaccurate answers.

Comment: @theTinMan Thank you for the suggestion. I am more than familiar with MCVE concept, and I am sorry I could not provide one. It was beyond my technical ability, this is all new to me. But in the case of the HTML I just thought it was irrelevant because I already knew that I was selecting the correct page elements. My question was not about the XPath path. It was about the casting of the number. Ultimately I turned out to be correct. The answerer did not edit after I commented there, but my solution was to use Ruby rather than XPath to perform the count, avoiding the casting entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the count outside the method.

```
row_count_on_page.count
```

As you are currently using, after the second member of find is evaluated you will have something like:

```
row_count_on_page = page.find(:xpath, "10.0")
```

which is not a valid xpath.

Comment: The XPath is working correctly as-is. It's actually an improvement from my first attempt, when I didn't include `count` in the XPath, and got a "Ambiguous match, found 10 elements matching xpath (Capybara::Ambiguous)" error.

Comment: You should check manually the value returned in the browser, if returns a number then is not ok because you need an xpath selector.Please not that you might have different methods for finding the first element and finding all the elements, one should return the first result and the other should return an array with all the elements.Xpath selector should return some elements, with count will not, it will return a number.

Comment: Ah, the first time I read your answer I misunderstood what you meant. I thought you were suggesting `row_count_on_page.count = page.find(...` but now I see you meant to call `count` after the find method. I have solved it by doing as you said, and also replacing `find` with `all`.